# How can I use IntelliJ to make Minecraft mods?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I'm starting out creating Minecraft mods with my son.

I've seen one YouTube tutorial which sets up project with Eclipse.

Since I don't like Eclipse much, I ask: how would I setup IntelliJ or Android Studio(if feasible) to develop Minecraft mods?

My son specifically want to create roller coaster mods.

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! "Is it possible to..." is kindof a yes/no question, and asking for tutorial calls for link-only answers (which we don't like here). Asking how it's done should get you better answers :)

Comment: Download Forge. Open the readme. Follow the "if using IntelliJ..." instructions.

Comment: @Draco18s thanks, can you make it an answer so I can accept..

Answer (score 3):

1. Download IntelliJ
2. Download Minecraft Forge from https://files.minecraftforge.net/, you'll want the MDK

   - Depending on your needs, the recommended version is fine, but as changes are being made regularly, downloading the most current might be beneficial.
3. Extract the zip into a new folder, I use a nested structure where I have one folder called "Minecraft Mods" and inside that a folder for each version of Forge (e.g. "Forge 1.12.1-2462" and "Forge 1.14.4-39"). Inside each of those is another folder that contains the zip archive contents (I used to skip this inner folder, but the project setup changed and Eclipse didn't like things; not sure how IntelliJ plays). I use this structure so that when I update from one version to another, I have an old workspace that still runs.
4. Open the readme and follow the directions:

> If you prefer to use IntelliJ:
>
> 1. Open IDEA, and import project.
> 2. Select your build.gradle file and have it import.
> 3. Run the following command: "gradlew genIntellijRuns" (./gradlew genIntellijRuns if you are on Mac/Linux)
> 4. Refresh the Gradle Project in IDEA if required.

There may be additional issues if you are on a Mac (because of the auto-generated .DS_Store files that us Windows folk hate cleaning up; Minecraft will attempt to parse these as resources, and I can't find a posted solution atm) and you might run into an [issue with assets](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/77064-solved-modding-with-intellij-the-asset-problem/?tab=comments#comment-370253) (solution linked).

Answer (score 1):

A plugin on IntelliJ is available for mods and plugins development ([here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8327-minecraft-development)).

I didn't make mods yet, but the plugin development is

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).